# How to detect superscript with ItextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, superscript

Hy

I am using ITextSharp to parse a pdf file to text output.
I want to know if I can catch if the pdf contains subscript or superscript, does anyone knows how to make the difference between a normal character and a superscript in a pdf using ITextSharp, or other library ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I don't actually have any evidence for this but...

I would expect super/subscript to be identical to normal text.  It's the same font, just smaller.  If it happens to be on the same line as other text, super/sub scripts are raised and lowered - but you won't be able to detect that with some explicit meta-tag in a layout-oriented format such as PDF.

In other words, I'd *guess* that you need to identify super/subscripts by heuristics: finding text that's smaller and vertically displaced compared to other text on the "same" line.  Whether that's easy to do or not depends on the PDF creator and the details of ITextSharp, since even identifying a "line" is not necessarily straightforward.

Comment: can anyone Provide code to detect subscript and superscript using itextsharp?

Comment: You may want to ask a new question.  However, it might be closed as a duplicate, and I doubt you'll find such code.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to implement a bit of custom logic here. There is no tag denoting superscript/subscript in PDF, it is simply sitting upon a different baseline. In cases such as this, you will have to note your baseline (along with your height).
Some quick pseudo-code:

```
    //input -> curText
    if(curText.Baseline > previousText.Baseline && 
         curText.Baseline < (prevText.Baseline + prevText.Height))
    {
         // This is most likely superscript //
    }
    else if(curText.Baseline < previousText.Baseline &&
         prevText.Baseline < (curText.Baseline + curText.Height))
    {
         // This is most likely subscript //
    }
    else
    {
         // This is probably normal text //
    }
```

This solution requires you to organize the thoroughly unorganized nature of a PDF file. In the past I have used List<> of a custom class meant to organize all text of a given y coordinate into arrays. Using something like this you can then compare the separate lines and do whatever work to them you might want before painting or otherwise transmitting them.